# jQuery Tablesorter - output-widget make output like table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this jQuery tablesorter:

http://tablesorter.com/docs/

https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-output.html

```
$(function () {

    var $table = $('table');
    
    $('.download').click(function(){
        $table.trigger('outputTable');
    });

    $table.tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widgets: ['zebra', 'output'],
        widgetOptions : { output_delivery : 'd'}
    });
});
```

and this is a simple [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/8763/)

The problem is that when you click Get CSV the data saved in this file is all in one line. It is unreadable.

How to make it look like a table with columns, like it's already in HTML view....it doesn't have to be csv...is there maybe some other plugin that can export more readable output?

#### UPDATE:

Output looks like this:

[image]

and what i want is this:

[image]

Comment: maybe a pdf or excel sheet output??

Comment: If you will open this file in excel it will be well formatted only

Comment: I am opening it in excel and it looks like this: see my question updated

Comment: there's nothing wrong with the CSV format. Probably you have to use the text import wizard in Excel and tell it to use commas as a separator. This is unrelated to tablesorter

Comment: Yes i know that there is nothing wrong with CSV output....but what i want is this: see my question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the separator to `;`.

**Modified JS:**

```
$(function() {
  var $table = $('table');

  $('.download').click(function() {
    $table.trigger('outputTable');
  });

  $table.tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widgets: ['zebra', 'output'],
    widgetOptions: {
      output_delivery: 'd',
      output_separator: ';'
    }
  });
});
```

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/8764/

***UPDATE***

After your comment I made one more modification to replace `.` on numeric columns to `,`:

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
  var $table = $('table');

  $('.download').click(function() {
    $table.trigger('outputTable');
  });

  $table.tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widgets: ['zebra', 'output'],
    widgetOptions: {
      output_delivery: 'd',
      output_separator: ';',
      output_formatContent: function(c, wo, data) {
        if (c.parsers[data.$cell['0'].cellIndex].type !== 'numeric')
          return data.content;
        return data.content.replace(/\./ig, ',');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

New jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/8781/

Comment: i have one little problem now....because i'm in germany we separate the decimal numbers with a dot "." and when i export the data in .csv where ever i have decimal number it is converted to a date. How to fix this??

Comment: Yes...just a moment!

Comment: Here you go....look at the numeric column in .csv file http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/8780/ how to prevent those fields to be dates....maybe if i could replace the . dot with , comma

Comment: I will make a new question for this on SO

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40787656/jquery-tablesorter-exports-dates-instead-of-floats

Comment: I answered there and also modified my answer here.