# jQuery Tablesorter - exports dates instead of floats

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/8780/)

When i export my table to csv the floats are separated with decimal dot "."
and in excel the values are converted to dates instead of keeping them like they are in HTML table.

Is there a way to replace the dots with decimal comma ","

```
$(function () {

    var $table = $('table');

    $('.download').click(function(){
        $table.trigger('outputTable');
    });

    $table.tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widgets: ['zebra', 'output'],
        widgetOptions : { output_delivery : 'd', output_separator     : ';'}
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can config a `output_formatContent`, like this:

```
$(function() {
  var $table = $('table');

  $('.download').click(function() {
    $table.trigger('outputTable');
  });

  $table.tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widgets: ['zebra', 'output'],
    widgetOptions: {
      output_delivery: 'd',
      output_separator: ';',
      output_formatContent: function(c, wo, data) {
        if (c.parsers[data.$cell['0'].cellIndex].type !== 'numeric')
          return data.content;
        return data.content.replace(/\./ig, ',');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

You can check here: http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/8781/

Comment: Well son, i've got to say that whatever you get paid it's probably not enough! Say that to your boss if you have one!

Comment: Haha nice to help you.

Comment: You need this because data is the third parameter of the callback function. I took this from the official docs.

Comment: You can change the name of the parameter, if you prefer. I just used exactly the same as de docs.